# PYTHON: solving y=a+b*x where x is a predefined list

Tags: python, algorithm, list, linear-regression

As mentioned above, I was trying to solve the problem...
description: `y` is an empty list, each time the equation will be evaluated with `y=a+bx` where `x` is a list with no. of values in it, the evaluated answer for `y` will be added to the list named `y` (appended).
Now my problem is that I have tried almost every google search in for this solution but no avail, I am a beginner in Python.

I do have the block of code which I tried according to my beginner knowledge it didn't work

```
ERROR_SHOWN: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type numpy.float64
```

hope it helps in any way...

code:

```
y = []
for num in x:
   y=a+b*x
append(y)
print(y)
```

hope the information I've provided is helpful

Answer (score 3):

```
y = [a+b*num for num in x]
print(y)
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the following is the thing that you are trying to do.

```
y = []
for num in x:
   some_y = a+b*num
   y.append(some_y)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = []

a = 1
b = 2

for num in x:
    result = a+b*num
    y.append(result)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

here with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
a, b= 10,5
y = a+b*x
y
```